# error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Cadena'

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

i have the next errors when i try to compile my code:

> ```
> ./usuario.h:64:37: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Cadena'
>                 Cadena direccion() const { return direccion_; }
>                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
> ./../P1/Cadena/cadena.h:11:3: note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'Cadena' has a user-declared move constructor
>                 Cadena(Cadena&& c);
> ```

```
usuario.cpp:14:3: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Cadena'
         nombre_(nombre), apellidos_(apellidos), direccion_(direccion), password_(password){
         ^       ~~~~~~
```

The constructors in Cadena are:

```
Cadena(const size_t t=0, const char c=' ');
Cadena(Cadena&& c);
Cadena(const char* c);
```

And the move-constructor:

```
Cadena::Cadena(Cadena&& c) : tam_(c.tam_) {
    cadena_ = new char[tam_+1];
    strcpy(cadena_, c.cadena_);    
    c.tam_=0;
    delete[] c.cadena_;
    c.cadena_ = new char[1];
    c.cadena_ = "";
}
```

The declaration in usuario.h are:

```
//........
public:
     Cadena id() const { return id_; }
//....
private:
     Cadena direccion_;
```

The class Cadena is work perfectly, but now i need use it and the compiler drop those errors.
I think that i don´t doing nothing special, only return/assign a object of type Cadena..

I expect yours feedback,

best regards.

Comment: That error message explains everything, what part are you having trouble with? You're trying to return a copy of `Cadena`, which is not possible due to the reason explained in the error message. Maybe you need to provide a copy-constructor as well, or explicitly default one?

Comment: effectively, i delete the copy constructor and i believed the move-constructor had the same function as the copy. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, copying and moving are two very distinct operations, and you need the copy-constructor when copying. You could fix your code by changing the offending line to `Cadena direccion() const { return std::move(direccion_); }`, but that's probably not the behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, it´s all i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for completeness, the Standard mandates the behavior from your compiler warning:

**12.8 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]**

> 7 If the class deﬁnition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   constructor, one is declared implicitly. **If the class deﬁnition
>   declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
>   implicitly declared copy constructor is deﬁned as deleted;** otherwise,
>   it is deﬁned as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the
>   class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared
>   destructor.

So if you want copying behavior, you will have to provide a copy constructor and copy assignment operator yourself.

However, looking at your move constructor, it appears that this doesn't provide any move semantics but rather deep copying (hint: what does `strcopy()` do? it sure doesn't move). So I would rename your current move constructor to the copy constructor, and provide a new move constructor that actually moves (i.e. re-assigns the `char` pointer or whatever is the handle to the actual data in your class).